# How to Retrieve Minimum Wage Data

Tags: data-request, economics, labor

I am trying to find minimum wage data in the API as it is shown on this page: https://www.dol.gov/whd/minwage/america.htm#stateDetails.

I know that there is the https://data.dol.gov/get/publications_view data table, however, is there a way to search this table for minimum wage data?  Should I be looking somewhere else?

Also, it would be a bonus if I could get minimum wage data at the city level, as I know cities like Pasadena, CA have a high minimum wage than the rest of the state.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1:** [This link](https://www.dol.gov/whd/state/stateMinWageHis.htm) from the page you shared contains historical minimum wage data for all 50 states and the Federal government.  You could scrape the tables from this page using `R` like so:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

html <- xml2::read_html(
  "https://www.dol.gov/whd/state/stateMinWageHis.htm"
) 

html %>%
  rvest::html_table(fill = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#>    State or other\r\n      jurisdiction                      1968 (a)
#> 1                        Federal (FLSA)                 $1.15 & $1.60
#> 2                               Alabama                           ...
#> 3                                Alaska                          2.10
#> 4                               Arizona 18.72 \r\n      - 26.40/wk(b)
#> 5                              Arkansas                   1.25/day(b)
#> 6                            California                       1.65(b)
#> 7                              Colorado      1.00 \r\n      - 1.25(b)
#> 8                           Connecticut                          1.40
#> 9                              Delaware                          1.25
#> 10                              Florida                           ...
...
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You'll get each HTML table parsed as a list of data frames.  Note that's you'll have to do a little bit of cleaning (e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`, `purrr::map_dfr`, and the `stringr` package may be helpful).

**Alternative 2:** You could acquire minimum wage for each state and the federal government as separate time series from [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/tags/series?t=minimum+wage).  If you're an R user, you can use a FRED API package like [`fredr`](https://github.com/sboysel/fredr) (Disclaimer: I am the package author.)

**Alternative 3:** The [Historical state and sub-state minimum wage data](https://equitablegrowth.org/working-papers/historical-state-and-sub-state-minimum-wage-data/) by the [Washington Center for Equitable Growth](https://equitablegrowth.org/).  From the data abstract:

> We introduce datasets of historical state and sub-state minimum wage
>   levels for the United States. From these daily minimum wage increases,
>   we create state and sub-state panels at daily, monthly, quarterly, and
>   annual frequencies. The state datasets span May 1974 to July 2016 and
>   the sub-state datasets include city and county changes from January
>   2004 to July 2016. Estimating teen wage and employment elasticities
>   using the state data generate very similar estimates to those
>   estimated using minimum wage data from other recent papers. For the
>   most recent version of these data and the code that produces them, see
>   our Github page.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those. They are good resources. I take it the minimum wage data is not in the API then?

Comment: I was unable to connect to the DOL labor API to help answer your question.  There seems to be an ongoing discussion of these issues [here](https://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/Developer/issues).  My hunch is that, no, minimum wage data in the exact format you're after is not exposed via this particular API.